# Detect location of column in html5

Tags: jquery, css, html

Is there a way to detect the location or block of a column created using the `-webkit-column` methods? Can this column be accessed with jQuery once it is created?

Is there a way to access the nodes of a specific column?

Update:
Is there a way to get the horizontal position of an element?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible since a block can be on more one column.
And there's now nothing generated in the source code to resolve it. Maybe in further version of JQuery ?

EDIT : enventually you can perform some calculations with -webkit-column-count, height of the container and height of all its elements.